# How can i traverse and optimize my nested Array of objects and show in jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, data-structures

```
async function getCardsData() {
  const data = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:1337/api/bottom-cards?populate=*"
  );
  const json = await data.json();
  console.log(json);
  setCardItems(json?.data);
  console.log(cardItems, "result");
}
```

**My JSX:**

```
cardItems.map((ele) => {
  console.log(ele,'e');
  return (
    <div className="footer-cards bg-white bg-opacity-80 p-4 shadow-lg rounded-md text-black">
      <h2>{ele.attributes.heading}</h2>
      {ele.attributes?.card_sub_headings?.data.map(x => {
        return(
          <p>{x.attributes.title}</p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
})
```

How can I optimize my solution so as to not use the map two times in my JSX, as it has `O(n*m)` complexity?

Provided I might increase the content of my cardItems array as well.

Comment: I think this is ok for this datastructure (jsx is just javascript AFAIK, it would be different in Angular for example)

Comment: You can’t do any better than this (without using useMemo), why would you want to try? What problems are you observing?

Answer (score 0):

For optimal rendering performance, you should put unique keys on your `<div>` and `<p>` nodes so that [React can update the DOM efficiently](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys). Assuming your `attributes` object contains an `id`, you could update your code like this:

```js
cardItems.map((ele) => {
  console.log(ele,'e');
  return (
    <div key={ele.attributes.id} className="footer-cards bg-white bg-opacity-80 p-4 shadow-lg rounded-md text-black">
      <h2>{ele.attributes.heading}</h2>
      {ele.attributes?.card_sub_headings?.data.map(x => {
        return(
          <p key={x.attributes.id}>{x.attributes.title}</p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
})
```